# Nginx not forwarding URL child elements of location to proxy inside docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I have the following nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name ce.mysite.com;

  location /api/ {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    set $api ce-api;
    proxy_pass http://$api:3100/;
  }

}
```

On the oter end of ce-api (docker container), I have a nodejs server running listening on port 3100. This is working and I can `curl http://localhost:3100/auth/ping` inside the container and get a valid response back.

However, if I access my site via ce.mysite.com/api/auth/ping. I get a 404. Adding some logging into the container to check the route, it would appear that `auth/ping` is missing from the route.

My understand was that using trailing slashes on the route and the proxy *should* mean that everything after `api` will be forwarded (in fact, I have a similar setup working where the nodejs server isn't inside a docker container).

Any idea what's happening?

Note: The nodejs server is an express server running on PM2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the network driver the container of app using.

I'm not sure but as per my knowledge I got from you, I can also doubt that the issue might be related to how the proxy_pass directive is configured in your nginx setup.

In your case, since you're accessing ce.mysite.com/api/auth/ping, nginx will remove /api/ before passing the request to the backend server, which means the backend server will receive a request for /auth/ping. If your backend server is expecting requests with /api/ prefix, it won't find the route /auth/ping and hence return a 404.

```
location /api/ {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    set $api ce-api;
    proxy_pass http://$api:3100/api/;
}
```

or try

```
location /api/ {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    set $api ce-api;
    rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://$api:3100;
```

in the second configuration, the rewrite directive is used to capture the part of the URI that comes after /api/ and pass it to the proxy without including the /api part. This way, the request to ce.mysite.com/api/auth/ping should correctly be forwarded to http://ce-api:3100/auth/ping.

save then run syntax error test by nginx

```
sudo nginx -t
```

if everything is good, restart nginx to get the new configurations:

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: The node server is expecting `/auth/ping` as per my test inside the container which works like: `curl http://localhost:3100/auth/ping` (notice without the API).
For now, I've just rebuilt my nodejs server so it expects the `/api` part to at least get it working but I want to understand what's going on. I didn't think of looking at the network setup though so that's a good call. Will check what options I have. Worth noting, I have other proxy's (for containerised apps) which seem to be working OK ...

Comment: Just re-read your second config part. That might just do it. Going to try! :)

Comment: That second config of removing the api part did it. Thanks very much. I'm happy with solution. Still intrigued why the slashes at the end of the location and the proxy didn't automatically do this though :)

Comment: @webnoob pleased to help you :)  Sure I will try to explain it as much as i can. The trailing slashes in the location block are used for different purposes and do not automatically handle appending paths or removing them. In the location block, the trailing slash indicates whether Nginx should try to match the request URL exactly or if it should try to match the URL plus any additional path components. For example: If you have location /example/, it will match requests like /example/, /example/foo, /example/foo/bar, etc. If you have location /example, it will only match requests like /example.

Answer (score 0):

That case, I think you need samples for Nginx proxy and zero-downtime deployment method.

What about referring to some samples like this?

https://github.com/Andrew-Kang-G/docker-blue-green-runner

- Use Docker & Docker-Compose
- With your project and its only Dockerfile, Docker-Blue-Green-Runner handles the rest of the Continuous Deployment (CD) process with Consul. Nginx allows your project to be deployed without experiencing any downtime.
- Consul & Registrator supported but they doesn't affect the availability of Nginx.
- Consider careful exceptional cases
- Available on one server machine